# Delphi hour:minutes input in a tEdit

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm out of ideas so I appeal to the immense StackOverflow supermind. What I want is to have a a tedit or whatever text control that lets me input text with the following format: "nnnnnn:nn" where n is an integer. Examples: If I type "100" I want a "100:00" text property. If I type "123:1" I should get "123:01". May be I should only type numbers in a calculator style with the ":" separator at a fixed position. I want rejected something like this "10 : 1", "10:95" (minutes 0-59), "0100:10", etc. Any ideas or component?
Greetings, Marcelo.

Comment: why does typing 123:1 becomes 123:01 and not 123:10 ?

Comment: OK. Could be as you suggest @GuidoG

Answer (score 1):

Any formatting that changes in input text during entry is bad, so the following shows you how to do it, but input is only changed on exiting the field or pressing the enter key:

Edit 1 is the edit field in question. Edit2 is simply there to allow the tab key to exit Edit1.

Note that I am using standard evets and event name (OnKeyPress and OnExit)

```
unit Unit10;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, System.StrUtils, Vcl.Mask;

type
  TForm10 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    procedure Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
    procedure Edit1Exit(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    function EntryValid( const pVal : string ) : boolean;
  end;

var
  Form10: TForm10;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TComboBox }

procedure TForm10.Edit1Exit(Sender: TObject);
var
  iPos : integer;
  iCheck : string;
  i1 : string;
begin
  iPos := Pos( ':', Edit1.Text );
  if iPos > 0 then
  begin
    // we already know there can only be one ':'
    i1 := Copy( Edit1.Text, 1, iPos );
    iCheck := Copy(Edit1.Text, iPos + 1 );
    if iCheck = '' then
    begin
      Edit1.Text := i1 + '00';
    end
    else if StrToInt( iCheck ) < 10 then
    begin
      Edit1.Text := i1 + '0' + iCheck;
    end
    else
    begin
      // already correct, so ignore
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    Edit1.Text := Edit1.Text + ':00';
  end;
end;

procedure TForm10.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  // only allow numbers and a single :
  case Key of
    '0'..'9': ;
    ':':
    begin
      if Pos( ':', Edit1.Text ) <> 0 then
      begin
        Key := #0; // don't allow
        Beep;
      end;
    end;
    #13:
    begin
      Key := #0; // silently this time
      Edit1Exit( Sender );
    end
    else
    begin
      Key := #0;
      Beep;
    end;
  end;
end;

function TForm10.EntryValid(const pVal: string): boolean;
var
  iPos : integer;
  iCheck : string;
begin
  iPos := Pos( ':', pVal );
  if iPos > 0 then
  begin
    // we already know there can only be one ':'
    iCheck := Copy( pVal, iPos + 1 );
    if iCheck = '' then
    begin
      Result := TRUE;
    end
    else if StrToIntDef( iCheck, 60 ) < 60 then
    begin
      Result := TRUE;
    end
    else
    begin
      Result := FALSE;
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    Result := TRUE;
  end;
end;

end.
```